# Akka HTTP AuthenticationFailedRejection cause

Tags: scala, authentication, jwt, akka-http

I've created a directive that will validate a JWT token:

```
  def authenticated: Directive[Unit] = optionalHeaderValueByName("Authorization")
    .flatMap[Unit] {
      case Some(token) => Jwt.decode(token, "secret", Seq(JwtAlgorithm.HS256)) match {
        case Failure(_: JwtExpirationException) =>
          // TODO the rejection handler needs to know that the token is expired.
          reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsRejected, HttpChallenge("JWT", None)))
        case Failure(_: JwtException) =>
          // TODO the rejection handler needs to know that the token is invalid.
          reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsRejected, HttpChallenge("JWT", None)))
        case Success(_) =>
          // TODO read token and validate user id
          pass
      }
      case None => reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing, HttpChallenge("JWT", None)))
}
```

The problem is that their are only 2 causes: `CredentialsRejected` and `CredentialsMissing`. I need to be able to add an extra rejection cause to show if a token is expired. But the causes both extend from a sealed class so I can't make my own..

Is there a way to create a custom cause or to add some data to the `CredentialsRejected` cause so it is possible to check the reason of the rejection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (quite outdated, because it is in relation to spray instead of akka-http) [comment](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/943) to a request that looks like yours is: create your own Rejection instead of using AuthenticationFailedRejection to handle this.